# Does nginx block on long requests?

Tags: nginx

I've read a couple similar questions but haven't gotten the answer I'm looking for.
If Nginx is using an evented model, my understanding is that any work that happens in the event loop is blocking the event loop.  So does it block, or does it use some other idea to avoid blocking the event loop if there's some slow request.  Is it based on the idea that there are no slow requests in a typical http situation?

Comment: What do you mean by "slow request"?

Comment: let's say someone was on a super slow connection and you were transferring 1mb of data to them and that took a minute.

Comment: Nginx uses nonblocking interfaces provided by operating system. See `man 2 accept` `SOCK_NONBLOCK` for example.